# Spinor index contractions for baryons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, quantum-chromodynamics, baryons

For an $SU(N)$ QCD with $N_f$ flavours one writes baryons as
\begin{equation}
B^{{a_1}…a_{{N}_f}}=\epsilon^{i_1…i_N}\psi_{i_1}^{a_1}… \psi_{i_N}^{a_{Ν_f}}
\end{equation}
by contracting the colour indices $i_1,… ,i_N$ with the invariant $\epsilon$ tensor and $a_1,…, a_{{N}_f} $ are the flavour indices. In all examples I’ve seen, the authors leave the spinor indices implicit. I’d like to be more careful about this. What are the possible ways we can contract the spinor indices? In particular for odd $N$ how can we contract the Lorentz indices to get a spin $1/2$ baryon?

For clarity I’m happy with the representations of states but am trying to understand the field operators which support these states.

Comment: To be clear, you are completely cool about the [*states*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model#Baryons), but are curious about  field operators supporting such states?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes exactly! Thanks for making this clear :)

Comment: You might update your question, to leave no-one in doubt. An overview of such interpolating field operators is [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5328).

Comment: Do the spin indices have to be contracted at all? Why can't they be open? If we have e.g. 3 spin-1/2-representations (quarks) their tensor product can be written via [Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) as a combination of states with total spin 1/2 and 3/2, so spin-1/2 baryons should be included in that, right?

Comment: For a spin 1/2 baryon, you need a spinor operator, or a superposition of such, as detailed in the linked review. For a spin 3/2, a spinor-vector operator, etc... So two of the three quark spinor indices are contracted, with rich combinatorics. If you don't care about the Lorentz group, you just add spins and Clebsch, which is what you do for simple NR states, as in the WP illustrations.

Comment: ... if you *did* care about the Lorentz representation, as you appear to, you have to do [due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Applications) cf "Off-diagonal direct sums".